# With equal heights constrain between two views, how do I decide which view shrinks/inflates?

Tags: ios, autolayout

Lets say I have a horizontal stack view, wherein 2 stack views are present (each internal stack view naturally represents a column). Every internal stackview has 2 labels. Now I set the equal with constraint and assert that the first constraint in the first internal stackview needs to have equal height to the first view in the second stack view. How do I decide, whether the first shrinks, or the second grows?

[image]

in this case the green view grew. How do I make the yellow view shrink?

Comment: You do so by giving the views different Content Compression Resistance and Hugging priorities.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to set both. But, you have to make sure you're not defining an impossible layout. Do you want the TopRight label to be as wide as needed to fit the text? What happens if it's so wide it completely squeezes the TopLeft label to 1-pt wide? Do you want your "columns" to be equal widths? Do you want the TopRight label to only be as tall as needed, and force the TopLeft label to truncate?

Answer (score 0):

You can decide whether first view in the first stack view should shrink or the first view in the second stack view grows by setting **Content Hugging Priority** and **Content Compression Resistance Priority** for both.

If you want view in the first stack view shrinks then set Vertical Content Compression Resistance Priority for the first view in first stack view to be less than Vertical Content Hugging Priority of the first view in second stack view and vice versa for the opposite scenario.

For example set Vertical Content Compression Resistance Priority for the first view in first stack view to be 250 and Vertical Content Hugging Priority of the first view in second stack view should be 251. In this case view in first stack view will get shrink.